# undefined error on using self.calculate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

i want to perform mysql function GROUP_CONCAT in rails.
i am using calculate method of active record.
like this self.calculate(:group_concat, :id)

i dont know if this is the correct way.

any idea on how to perform group_concat in rails?
along with find method of activerecord.

Comment: You can always execute any raw SQL you want.

Comment: yes sergio, but i will have to change much code in that case. since i am using find method of active record it is already taking care of generating queries. so is there a way to integrate group_concat without using raw sql queries? and thnx for your response btw..

Comment: If you have actual SQL query for this problem.. Post here that too.

Comment: I've never been able to get group_concat to work well with rails, generally I've found the best option is to do Model.select('GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ", ") as alias').group('standard_group_by_field')

Answer (score 0):

As @Camway notes above, this is easily done using the proper Rails methodology for JOINing, SELECTing, and GROUPing. As an example, let's say I have users and regions, a user can have 0-to-many regions and a region can have 0-to-many users.

Here's my **Region** model:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: id (integer), code (string)
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Here's my **User** model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: id (integer), email (string)
  has_and_belongs_to_many :regions
end
```

There is, of course, also a **regions_users** join table with region_id and user_id integer fields.

To get a general-purpose GROUP_CONCAT working that pulls the codes of all the regions each user is attached to, I just need to add a class method like this to the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: id (integer), email (string)
  has_and_belongs_to_many :regions

  class << self
    def regions_listing
      joins(:regions)
      .select("DISTINCT users.email, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT regions.region_code ORDER BY regions.region_code) AS regions_list")
      .group("users.email")
      .order("users.email")
    end
  end
end
```

So, with just that bit of code in place, the following pulls all the users, ordered by email address.

```
ruby > User.regions_listing
 => [#<User email: "joe@blow.com">,#<User email: "sally@mae.com">,#<User email: "billy@bob.com">,#<User email: "jane@doe.com">,#<User email: "big@ed.com">]
```

Each of these returned objects has a **#regions_list** attribute reader that will give you the group-concatenated list of the codes for the regions attached to that user through the regions_users table.

This can be seen with a simple call to #map:

```
ruby > User.regions_listing.map { |u| [u.email, u.regions_list] }
 => [["joe@blow.com", "0,1,2,3,4,5"], ["sally@mae.com", "1,2,5"], ["billy@bob.com", "0,4"], ["jane@doe.com", "3"], ["big@ed.com", "2,3,4,5"]]
```

Note that since this is using the appropriate AREL-backed AR methods, it is **chainable**. That is, you can add **".regions_listing"** on to the end of just about any AR query against the User model and it will give you the group-concatenated method/data for whatever User objects your query picked up.

As such:

```
ruby > User.where("users.email like 'b%'").regions_listing.map { |u| [u.email, u.regions_list] }
 => [["billy@bob.com", "0,4"], ["big@ed.com", "2,3,4,5"]]
```

And you can also get at the data in your manufactured #regions_list field using a HAVING, for instance to find all the users attached to both region 0 and region 4:

```
ruby > User.regions_listing.having("regions_list LIKE '%0%4%'").map { |u| [u.email, u.regions_list] }
 => [["joe@blow.com", "0,1,2,3,4,5"], ["billy@bob.com", "0,4"]]
```